# MFC CEdit object in a CDialogEx object

Tags: c++, mfc

I'd be very grateful if anyone could help me with this? I'm trying to create a dialog box with a text box in it for receiving error messages. I've added ON_WM_CREATE to the message map, and written this function which the debug goes through, but the object doesn't display.

```
int CImportDatatoAPMDlg::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT LpCreateStruct)
{
    if(CWnd::OnCreate(LpCreateStruct) == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    CEdit *MessageBox = new CEdit;

    MessageBox->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,CRect(100, 200, 450, 150), this, 0x1552);

    return 0;
}
```

Do I have to make a dummy box when I'm designing the dialog box. I've already done this for the rest of the controls? I'm also wondering where I give this object a number ID combination?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1):

You normally should use VisualStudio resource editor to add controls to your dialog. If you want to do it manually then create and add controls in your overriden OnInitDialog method:

```
BOOL CImportDatatoAPMDlg::OnInitDialog() {
 BOOL bRes = CDialog::OnInitDialog();

   CEdit *MessageBox; // !!! put it into class definition
   MessageBox = new CEdit

   MessageBox->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,CRect(100, 200, 450, 150), this, 0x1552);

   return bRes;
}
```

Comment: That hasn't worked I'm afraid. I get a grey featureless box overlaying some of the other items on the box. I'd really like to learn to do this programmatically, and have more control. Where should I put the define for something like #define IDC_TEXTBOX 1552

Comment: Here is link to simple code, it looks exactly like above http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zxw3b4a(v=vs.80).aspx,

Comment: You can put  this define anywhere , iit is of interest only to you, it would normally be placed in resources.h